# How to change the clearcase "registry on server host " automated way?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

We are working in 2 projects and unfortuantely we have to switch between 2 replicas .

So we are changing registry on server host information by typing cc.cpl in run programs and change it manually .

Is there any way to change it automatically? may be cleartool command would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`cc.pl` opens the ClearCase control panel applet, which allows you to change the ClearCase Registry Server (in the first tab).

The registry is stored in

```
LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Atria\ClearCase\CurrentVersion
AtriaRegy
```

You can change it directly through regedit.

Note that, since it involves HKLM (and not HKCU), elevated privileges may be require to modify that value (depending on the gpo, Microsoft Groupe Policy Objects, in effect on your workstation).

Comment: Where can i find it on linux ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are clearcase admin you can think of setting up a clearcase cross registry server/multiple registry server. Just use `cleartool register -vob` and `cleartool mktag -vob` commands to see the VOB in the other registry server.

[multiple registry server](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/r_rgy_multi.htm)

So that Developer need not to change the registry server every time.